# Laravel How to pass parameter to Accessor method in model via where condition while query building?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Accessor method in Collection Model getSizesAttribute, which returns array of available sizes eg: ['S','L'], Now I need to get Models with have size 'S'. like:

```
$collections = $collections->where('sizes','S');
```

But sizes is array, could I manipulate this anyhow so that I could check returns only if sizes have specific size.

I tried making another method getIsSizeAttribute, like:

```
public function getIsSizeAttribute($size){
      return in_array($size,$this->sizes);
}
```

Now How could I user this in Where condition like

```
$collections = $collections->where('is_size','S');
```

Comment: I can notice a wrong naming, but I am not sure if it will help. In your case
you have `is_size` custom attribute and you search for `is_sizes` so modify it to this
`$collections->where('is_size','S');` and try if it works

Comment: @nakov Tried with is_size too, still not working modified question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) and [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) only run skin-deep, after the query's already been executed.  You could use [Collection::filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter) as Bangnokia suggests, but that wouldn't give you any performance benefit of actually applying the condition to the initial request.

I think what you're looking for here is a [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes).  Add something like this to your Model class:

```
public function scopeSize(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, $size)
{
    return $query->whereIn('sizes', $this->sizes[$size]);
}
```

And access it like this:

```
$collection = $model->size('S')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter` on collection

```
$collections = $collections->filter(function($item, $index) {
    return in_array('S', $item->sizes);
});
```